# Command to convert selected lines to HTML bulleted list in Sublime Text?

Tags: html, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Whenever I have a series of lines that are supposed to be a bulleted list (UL) in Sublime Text 3, I need to repeat these steps:

1. Select the lines
2. Use "split selection into lines (shift-command-L)
3. Wrap selection with tag (ctrl-W) and type `LI`
4. Re-select the 4 lines
5. Wrap selection *again* with `UL` this time (or just manually type UL and /UL)

This is tedious.  Does anyone know of a built-in command, a plug-in, or a macro that will take selected lines, wrap each line with an LI tag and the selection with the UL tags in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a mac:

- Shift+Cmd+P: Command Palette
- Filter the list with "wrap with abb"
- Notice the input box at the bottom of the window
- Type and enter: ul>li*

Also, one can select the text and press Ctrl+W and use ul>li*

Comment: Very nice.  It should be noted that you do not have to split the selection into lines first (shift-command-L) as I was doing at first for this to work.  In fact, if you do, each line becomes a `ul>li`.  Thanks for a great tip.

Comment: Doesn't work in Monterey.
1. "Wrap with abb" is not found in the list
2. Ctrl+W does nothing

Answer (score 14):

You can easily achieve this if you have the [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) plugin installed. The feature that you're after is called ["Wrap with abbreviation"](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/).

Steps needed:

1. Select the block of text
2. Press **CTRL+SHIFT+G** (on Windows), and;
3. enter **ul>li*** in the input field that opens up at the bottom of the window (same as where "Find" comes up).
4. Profit! :)

It's also possible to do some further cool stuff using [filters](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#removing-list-markers) with this as well. Be sure to check out the [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) docs.

Comment: Very nice.  I use Emmmet but was unaware of this ability. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiline select to insert `</li><li>` before every line. Remove all line breaks and add a line break after every `</li>`. Then manually wrap the result in `<ul></ul>`. It should work and look okay to the eye.

Or use the Emmet plugin to make a list like this: `ul>li*40`, press `ctrl+e` or `tab`, and multiline-select copypaste the desired text to `<li>here</li>`.

Comment: yeah, i was hoping for a single command, as in BBedit where you just select some lines and click.